# Regular expression for numbers not beginning with 0

Tags: java

I need to write a regular expression that can match any number.

A number can be positive or negative. If it is negative, then it should start with a '-'. If it is positive, it may start with a '+'. If it doesn't start with either '+' or '-' it is considered positive.

A number can't start with zeros, only if this number is zero itself. For example, 001 is not a valid number, but 0 is a valid number.

A number can have a fractional part. A delimiter between an integer part and a fractional part can be either '.' or ','. A fractional part can't have trailing zeros except all fractional part consists of single zero. For example, 1.01 and 1.0 are valid numbers, but 1.00 and 1.10 are not valid numbers.

Comment: What attempt have you made so far, and what difficulty are you having?

Comment: Please Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your attempt.

Comment: Java 
"\\b\\w{"+size+"}\\b"

Answer (score 2):

First condition:

```
^[+,-]{0,1}
```

Second condition:

```
(?:[1-9]\d*|0)
```

Third condition:

```
(?:^\.(?:0$|[0-9]*[^0]$))
```

Making last condition optional and end of string

```
*$
```

Putting it all together:

```
^[+,-]{0,1}(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:\.(?:0$|[0-9]*[^0]$))*$
```

You can test it on https://regex101.com/

Comment: Delimiter can be comma